# android - eclipse: display google maps using coordinates obtained using gps

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, gps

I am trying to create an app that will obtain the users location via gps, display the users location in google maps, and then update after a certain amount of time/movement.

I currently have an app that will obtain the users location via gps and update itself every 10meters/10,000 miliseconds, but currently all it does is display what the coordinates are. I have it set up to connect to google maps, but at the minute it is simply setting the map to some coordinates that I have manually entered myself.

How do I get it so the map will display the location based on the coordinates obtained via gps?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am very new to all this!

EDIT: heres my code so far!

```
package com.android.basicmap;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;

public class BasicMapActivity extends MapActivity {

private MapView mapView;
private MapController mapController;

private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  

    locationListener = new GPSLocationListener();

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
      LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
      0, 
      0, 
      locationListener);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setStreetView(true);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(16);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
  return false;
}

private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener 
{
  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
      GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
          (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
          (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
          "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + 
          " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude(), 
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      mapController.animateTo(point);
      mapController.setZoom(16);
      mapView.invalidate();
    }
  }


}
```

}

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! You will have a better chance of getting your question answered if you include a few _relevant_ code snippets. For example, you mentioned that you have the location update working but not the map update portion. It would probably be a good idea to include the _relevant_ snippets from your `Map` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a full-blown tutorial on that: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112044/GPSLocator-App-to-Find-Current-Nearest-Location-us

But come on, I found that by entering "android how to show gps location on google map", please, google more thoroughly and go through tutorials before posting such simple questions :)

Comment: this tutorial is exactly what I'm looking for, sadly I have had several attempts at completing it but I can't get it working! Thanks for posting it anyway though.

Comment: What does it say while not working? Let's get you through :) Also, if the answer is satisfactory, consider marking it as accepted - by clicking the little checkmark on the left.

Comment: I have completed the first parts of the tutorial: adding the map and the zoom controls, its the next part "add gps location' that's throwing me loads of errors! I have updated my code in my original post to show you where I am up to so far in the tutorial, maybe you can see where I am going wrong! Many thanks

Comment: Consider posting the errors as well, that'll help spotting the problem

Comment: I am getting an error at private class GPSLocationListener:

Multiple markers at this line
 - The type TESTActivity.GPSLocationListener must implement the inherited abstract method 
  LocationListener.onProviderDisabled(String)
 - The type TESTActivity.GPSLocationListener must implement the inherited abstract method 
  LocationListener.onStatusChanged(String, int, Bundle)
 - The type TESTActivity.GPSLocationListener must implement the inherited abstract method 
  LocationListener.onProviderEnabled(String)

Comment: and at: public void onLocationChanged(Location location)

Multiple markers at this line
 - implements android.location.LocationListener.onLocationChanged
 - The method onLocationChanged(Location) of type TESTActivity.GPSLocationListener must override a superclass 
  method

Comment: Oh, there's your problem) Note the ... in the tutorial. The implementing class should always either implement all methods of interface or be abstract. In your case, implement all methods. Eclipse is probably telling you the same thing right now. It must have underlined class name with red wavy thingie. Place cursor there, hit Ctrl+1 and choose "Add unimplemented methods", leave them empty. That should do it. You're very new to programming, aren't you? :)

Comment: YES THANK YOU! That has fixed it and got rid of the error :) yes this is all new to me, I'm an undergraduate student on more of a web design type of course and I'v never had any experience with java, but for my final year project I'm attempting to build an Android App! Many thanks I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Here, give this one a try, it seems less ambiguous: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

Comment: Ok. So, mark my answer as accepted then) Click on the little checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using `MapView`, the simplest thing to do is add an instance of `MyLocationOverlay` to the map, as Android will handle displaying the user's location for you.

```
map=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.whatever_your_mapview_id_is);
map.getOverlays().add(new MyLocationOverlay(this, map));
```

If for some reason you want to do that yourself rather than use the built-in facility, you can create your own `ItemizedOverlay` to display the point, and add an instance of your own custom overlay to the `MapView`.

Answer (score 0):

It's the best to use MyLocationOverlay if you want to display user's current location. However you have alternative of:

```
map.animateTo(GeoPoint);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that u've defined your mapview and mapcontroller

for that, first you neeed suscribe to the location update in your OnCreate  method like that: the code belows requests update every 1000ms or 10m

```
LocationManager lm;
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10f, this);
```

below you is my way to update my position on the map

```
@Override
GeoPoint p,P2, p3;
double lat=53,  double lng=4;
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.v(tag, "Location Changed");

        lat= (int) (location.getLatitude());
        lng= (int) (location.getLongitude());

        sb = new StringBuilder(512);

        noOfFixes++;

        p = new GeoPoint(
                (int) (location.getLatitude()*1E6), 
              (int) (location.getLongitude()*1E6));
        mapController.animateTo(p);
        mapController.setCenter(p);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Lat= " + lat + " Long= " + lng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




    }
```

Comment: I have tried using your code as best I could but I still can't get it working! I have edited my post to contain my code, I don't know if this will give you a better insight as to where I'm going wrong! Many thanks for your help.