# Based On Co-ordinates show location on MAP in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have made an app which gives you current latitude and longitude using GPS service.
Now i plan to show location on MAP based on this co-ordinates

I want to create 2 activities. 1st already created in which i am showing latitude and longitude in TextView. in 2nd activity i want to display map in which location will be displayed. to go from one activity to another i will use a button in 1st activity.

here is my code (Not Full)

```
protected LocationManager locMan;
protected LocationListener locLis;
protected Context contex;
TextView txtview;
String lat,provider;
protected String latitude,longtitude;
protected boolean gps_enable,network_enable;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#F44336")));

    txtview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locView);

    locMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){

     txtview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locView);
     txtview.setText("Latitude = "+loc.getLatitude()+", Longitude = "+ loc.getLongitude());
}
```

Note :- I have refer javapapers website for my current app

Regards

Comment: brother he is already displaying on MAP and having problem in marking but my problem is diff. I have co-ordinates and i want to display on MAP based on the co-ordinates what i have got.

Answer (score 0):

Create Map Activity and pass the location via bundle or save it in sharedpreference

```
public class MapActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

private GoogleMap googleMap;
FragmentManager fm;
private Location mLocation;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    // get location from bundle or sharedprefs
    // mLocation = ...

    try {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        }
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    MarkerOptions TP = new MarkerOptions().title("title").position(new LatLng(mLocation.getLatitude(), mLocation.getLongitude())).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_map_marker));
    googleMap.addMarker(TP);

}}
```

xml layout for this activity is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `MapView` and `MyLocationOverLay` to the map, as Android will handle displaying the user's location for you.

```
map=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.whatever_your_mapview_id_is);
map.getOverlays().add(new MyLocationOverlay(this, map));
```

Refer : [display google maps using coordinates obtained using gps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198773/android-eclipse-display-google-maps-using-coordinates-obtained-using-gps)

Comment: Note that this code is very outdated, with Google Maps API v2, all you need to do is call `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the location to the Maps Activity using a `LatLng` Object since it's parcelable, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106507/pass-longitude-and-latitude-with-intent-to-another-class/30107707#30107707).

Then, you could create a Marker in your MapsActivity, and use the CameraPosition class to move the map view to the specified location.

First, make sure that you have double values with the current location in your existing Activity:

```
//instance variables:
double lat;
double lon;
```

Set lat/lon in your `onLocationChanged()` callback:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){

     lat = loc.getLatitude(); //added
     lon = loc.getLongitude(); //added

     txtview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locView);
     txtview.setText("Latitude = "+loc.getLatitude()+", Longitude = "+ loc.getLongitude());
}
```

Create a Button in your layout in your existing Activity, and in the click listener you would create a `LatLng` object and send it in the Intent to the Maps Activity:

```
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LatLng fromPostion = new LatLng(lat, lon );

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putParcelable("location", fromPostion);

            Intent i = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
            i.putExtras(args);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Then, in your Maps Activity, you would get the `LatLng` object in `onCreate()` from the Bundle:

```
    LatLng latlng;  //Create as instance variable
```

In `onCreate()`:

```
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (b != null){
        latlng = (LatLng) b.getParcelable("location");
    }
```

Then, add the Marker at that location and set the camera position and zoom:

```
private void setUpMap() {

    mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title("My Location");

    // Changing marker icon
    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));

    Marker m = mMap.addMarker(marker);

    //move camera position and zoom to specified location
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(latlng).zoom(8).build();

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

}
```

Your full Maps Activity might look something like this:

```
public class MapsActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LatLng latlng;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    LocationManager manager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (b != null){
            latlng = b.getParcelable("location");
        }

        manager =(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();


        if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
                !manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Location is disabled")
                    .setMessage("Please enable your location")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 100);
                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();

        } else {
            Log.v("Connection Status", String.valueOf(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()));
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 100) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "location enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
                    manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "location enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //At least one provider enabled, connect GoogleApiClient
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }


    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Toast.makeText(this,"buildGoogleApiClient",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1F);

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }


    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();

            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }

        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {

        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title("My Location");

        // Changing marker icon
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));

        Marker m = mMap.addMarker(marker);

        //move camera position and zoom to specified location
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(latlng).zoom(8).build();

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionSuspended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionFailed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Log.d("locationtesting",  "lat: " + location.getLatitude() + " lon: " + location.getLongitude());

    }

}
```

layout xml for MapsActivity:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Note that you will also need to enable Google Maps in the Google Developer Console, and include Google Play Services in your build.gradle file (update version with the version that you are using):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
}
```

The last thing is to set up your AndroidManifest.xml for the Google Maps API v2:

permissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

meta-data tags, make sure they are inside the application tag:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="Your-API-Key" />
```

Comment: brother i have displayed progressDialog spinner but i want only till it fetches the location. If the Co-ordinates are found it should stop showing.

Comment: @user3384581 just dismiss the dialog in onLocationChanged().  Also, if you only need one location update, be sure to unregister for callbacks at that point.

Comment: Thanks dude.. I will do what you have told